# Using flag in java and calling it from one class to another class

Tags: java

I am using flag in one class

```
private  boolean spit_everythingtoLog = false;
public boolean readCommandLineParameters(String[] args) {
Logger log = Logger.getLogger(CLIReader.class);
Options options = new Options();

Option helpOpt = Option.builder("h").longOpt("help").desc("Usage Help").build();
options.addOption(helpOpt);

Option serverurl = Option.builder("url").longOpt("server url").desc("Server url").required().hasArg().argName("url").build();
options.addOption(serverurl);

Option userOpt = Option.builder("u").longOpt("user").desc(" User Name").hasArg().argName("user").required().build();
options.addOption(userOpt);

Option pwdOpt = Option.builder("p").longOpt("password").desc(" user password").hasArg().argName("password").required().build();
options.addOption(pwdOpt);



Option completeLoggerOpt = Option.builder("v").longOpt("completeLogger").desc("Complete Logger Info + Errors").hasArg().argName("Optional").build();
options.addOption(completeLoggerOpt);


try {
  CommandLineParser parser = new DefaultParser();
  CommandLine cmd = parser.parse(options, args, true);
  
  if(cmd.hasOption("v")){
  spit_everythingtoLog = true;
  }
  
  serverUrl = cmd.getOptionValue("url");
  user = cmd.getOptionValue("u");
  password = cmd.getOptionValue("p");
  streamName = cmd.getOptionValue("s");
  compList = cmd.getOptionValue("c");
  

}
catch (Exception e) {
 
    
  }


  }
  
 
 
  else 
  {
  log.info(e.getMessage());
  
  HelpFormatter formatter = new HelpFormatter();
  formatter.printHelp("AutoLockComponent ", options, true);
 
  }
  
  
 }


return false;
}

}
public String getUser() {
return user;
}


public String getPassword() {
return password;
}



public String getServerUrl() {
return serverUrl;
}


public boolean getFlag() {
return spit_everythingtoLog;
}
```

Now how to call that flag value in another class such as

```
  if(isLocked)
                        {
                          if(isLockedByMe)
                          {
                             //System.out.println("Do Nothing");
                            if(cli.getFlag()==true) 
                            {
                              log.info("Yes"); 
                            }
                            else 
                            {
                              
                             log.info("No");
                                
                            }
```

like i want that if user passes this arguement
-u stack -p flow -url https://www.google.com -v then print "Yes"
and if user passes this arguement
-u stack -p flow -url https://www.google.com  then print "No"

Can anyone please help me out in this?

Comment: my first guess would be, by calling this getter: public boolean getFlag() {
return spit_everythingtoLog;
}

Comment: @Stultuske but in my code it is there right or maybe can you point out in my code if possible? Thank you

Comment: Because spit_everythingtoLog is private, you can't read it from another class, unless you use a getter, public boolean getSpitToLog(), or you pass it as a parameter.

Comment: According to java programming conventions, the names of variables and methods should start with a lower case letter and use camelCase and no underscores (spitEverythingToLog).